# How to access a file more than once inside a loop or recursion function in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, file-io

I used the following method to print the nodes in a tree. This method exists in one of the application classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO; 

namespace AUV_Topology
{
    class SpanningTree
    {
        public static Graph graph = null;
        public static SpanningTree root = new SpanningTree();

        public static FileStream fs = new FileStream  ("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/SpanningTree.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

        public static void Print(SpanningTree parent, int level)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                sw.WriteLine("{0} Level : '{1}' ", new string(' ', 4 * level),level);
                sw.WriteLine(" , Row : '{0}', Col : '{1}'",parent.row, parent.col);
                sw.WriteLine("Length : '{0}'", parent.length);
                sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                if (parent.children != null)
                {
                    foreach (SpanningTree child in parent.children)
                    {
                        Print(child, level + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got error when I run my code as follows (
At "foreach" statement ):

Cannot access a closed file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of its `Dispose` logic the `StreamWriter` instance will close the underlying stream. So one solution will be to simply move the creation of the `FileStream` instance into your `Print` method.

In this case, in order to properly dispose resources, you could do something like this:

```
    public static void Print(SpanningTree parent, int level)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/SpanningTree.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            Print(parent, level, sw);
        }
    }

    private static void Print(SpanningTree parent, int level, StreamWriter sw)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        sw.WriteLine("{0} Level : '{1}' ", new string(' ', 4 * level), level);
        sw.WriteLine(" , Row : '{0}', Col : '{1}'", parent.row, parent.col);
        sw.WriteLine("Length : '{0}'", parent.length);
        sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        if (parent.children != null)
        {
            foreach (SpanningTree child in parent.children)
            {
                Print(child, level + 1, sw);
            }
        }
    }
```

Another solution is to use an alternative constructor of the `StreamWriter` type

```
public StreamWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen)
```

and pass `true` to the last argument `leaveOpen`. In this case, you'd want to make sure that you dispose off your resources somewhere outside of your method.

I would personally suggest you use the first approach - it's a little bit easier and this does not look like performance critical code...

Comment: That should still work identically, shouldn't it? We haven't changed the public interface.

Answer (score 1):

The `StreamWriter` will close/dispose the underlying `Stream` by default.

There is an overload constructor where you can pass the option to leave the stream open.

[`StreamWriter(
    Stream stream,
    Encoding encoding,
    int bufferSize,
    bool leaveOpen)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx)

But I would choose a different logic for that

```
public static void Print(
    SpanningTree root, 
    string filename )
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream( filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write );

    using ( StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( fs ) )
    {
        PrivatePrint( root, 0, sw );
    }
}

private static void PrivatePrint(
    SpanningTree parent, 
    int level, 
    StreamWriter sw )
{
    sw.WriteLine( "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" );
    sw.WriteLine( "{0} Level : '{1}' ", new string(' ', 4 * level), level );
    sw.WriteLine( " , Row : '{0}', Col : '{1}'", parent.row, parent.col );
    sw.WriteLine( "Length : '{0}'", parent.length );
    sw.WriteLine( "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" );

    if ( parent.children != null )
    {
        foreach ( SpanningTree child in parent.children )
        {
            PrivatePrint( child, level + 1, sw );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can take the Filestream also in the using block. Filestream implements IDisposable. using (var fs = new FileStream(...)){using StreanWriter....}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a using statement in the recursive manner you are doing. The reason is as follows:

After the last recursive call completes it disposes of the resource (using statement goes out of scope). When the second to last recursive call tries to dispose the resource (its using statement goes out of scope) it throws an exception because the resource was already disposed.

Consider the following console app code exhibiting the same behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/Test/SpanningTree.txt", FileMode.Append,
            FileAccess.Write);

        public static void Print(int level)
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                sw.WriteLine("{0} Level : '{1}' ", new string(' ', 4*level), level);
                sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                if (level < 10)
                {
                    Print(level + 1);
                }

            }

        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Print(1);
        }

    }
}
```

There are many ways to fix this issue I will demonstrate one below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/Test/SpanningTree.txt", FileMode.Append,
            FileAccess.Write);

        public static void Print(StreamWriter sw, int level)
        {

            sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine("{0} Level : '{1}' ", new string(' ', 4 * level), level);
            sw.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            if (level < 10)
            {
                Print(level + 1);
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {

                Print(1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, split `Print` into two:

1. Data generating
2. File writing

Something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<String> Data(SpanningTree tree, int level) {
  yield return $"-----------------------------------------------------------------";
  yield return $"{new string(' ', 4 * level)} Level : '{level}' ";
  yield return $" , Row : '{parent.row}', Col : '{parent.col}'";
  yield return $"Length : '{parent.length}'";
  yield return $"-----------------------------------------------------------------";

  if (parent.children != null) 
    foreach (SpanningTree child in parent.children)
      foreach (string line in Data(child, level + 1))
        yield return line;
}
```

Then print the data out:

```
public static void Print(SpanningTree parent, int level) {
  if (null == parent)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");  
  else if (level < 0) 
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("level");   

  File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/SpanningTree.txt", Data(parent, level)); 
}
```